# Вывод сообщения-меню в батнике

Tags: windows-7, bat

Как сделать батник с выводом сообщения-меню, где 1=пример: запуск одного приложения (или сайта), 2 = запуск еще одного.

Comment: @гарри, Согласно правилам форума, пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: я делаю свою 1 программу на cmd 
Я сделал её(точнее всё кроме функций(что бы при нажатие на 1 открывался сайт и т.д. и т.п.))
как я не пытался я не понимаю какая нужна для этого команда

Comment: Вы для начала, хоть какие-то [основы пройдите](http://www.philosoft.ru/batniki.zhtml). Тогда, возможно, что и сами сможете спраиться.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку буду учиться

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно изобретать велосипед. Начиная с windows xp есть команда choice позволяющая пользователю делать выбор.

Смотрите choice /?

Результат выбора хранится в переменной %errorlevel%

Comment: Будет наверняка полезно знать ещё про timeout /? А то есть любители делать паузу через ping localhost -n 5 >nul 

:-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Держи код :)

```
@Echo Off

:X_LOOP
Set /P $X=Make Your Choice Padavan!: (1 - ya.ru; 2 - calc; n - exit)? (1/2/n):
If /I Not "%$X%"=="1" If /I Not "%$X%"=="2" If /I Not "%$X%"=="n" GoTo X_LOOP

If /I "%$X%"=="1" CMD /c "%PROGRAMFILES%/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe" ya.ru
If /I "%$X%"=="2" CMD /c  calc.exe
If /I "%$X%"=="n" Exit 1

Echo Done!
PAUSE
```

Comment: Вы всю жизнь собираетесь программировать за топикстартера? Он так ничему не научится. Лучше бы разжевали основные команды.

Comment: я просто делюсь своим хорошим настроением! ;)

Comment: спасибо за код я смог сделать 1 программу я бы поставил + но у меня всего лишь репутация 1